# How to separate integer to 2 other integers? C/C++

Tags: c++, c, split, integer

I have a small problem. I have numbers from 00000001 to 99999999, and they have to be divided into 000 00001 and 999 99999, respectively, and put them in different variables. Who knows elegant solution for this?

Comment: Voted for closure: this sounds like a homework problem that you've put no effort into. Please make an attempt at coding this yourself, and then post what you tried and an explanation of why it isn't good enough.

Comment: what have you tried so far? post a self-contained code example and possible error message

Comment: How you define `00000001` in C++ code?

Comment: This sounds a lot like the Karatsuba multiplication algorithm.  Look that up.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare, I don `t know almost nothing about C :) (VBA me more native) Just now faced with the problem that can not be solved in VBA. The program was created for transforms  laid CARD ID wiegand ->touch memory ID.

Comment: @40two 00000001 (and any other numbers) - string in txt file

Comment: @SergeyKuchin - Which is why you shouldn't be posting here. We're not here to teach you the basics (there's plenty of tutorial websites, classes, and books out there that can teach you those.) We're here to help you when you have bugs in your first attempt at the code, or to help you optimize your code if it's slow, not to write your code from scratch for you.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare - Of course "my bad". Before writing, I was looking for on this site and on other sites and in books. But there are only examples of how to divide the number like 12345 -1-2-3-4-5. I had an idea to impose a "mask", but this method is worse than your (more lines of code + assembler)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use division to get the first part and modulus to get the second part:

```
void splitter(int number) {
    printf("First part: %i", number / 100000);
    printf("Second part: %i", number % 100000);
}
```

Comment: How would that print `000` and `00001`?

Comment: I mostly use Python, not C++, but you I'm sure there's some padding argument you can stick in the string formatter. Something like `%3i` instead of `%i`, probably. I was intentionally minimal in my answer, only putting as much effort into writing my answer as the asker put into writing their question.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

1. You'd need to convert them into strings and then split them, and then parse them back as integers.
2. Alternatively, you can divide the number by 10000, the results will become your first variable. You then do the modulus of 10000, the result will give you your second variable.

I'd personally pick the second option.